# RoutePrefix ignored for controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a web API targeting .NET Framework 4.8.
This is how the web app is initialized:

```
        var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver
        {
            ConstraintMap =
            {
                ["apiVersion"] = typeof(ApiVersionRouteConstraint)
            }
        };
        var defaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(3, 0);

        httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver, new VersionAwareDirectRouteProvider(defaultApiVersion));
        httpConfiguration.AddApiVersioning(o =>
        {
            o.ReportApiVersions = false;
            o.DefaultApiVersion = defaultApiVersion;
            o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = false;
            o.ErrorResponses = new CustomRoutingErrorResponseProvider();
        });
```

Due to o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = false all endpoints require the version to be specified.

From this rule I want to exclude the ping controller

```
[Route("/[controller]")]
public class PingController : BaseController
```

Although the call is made without the version in it, 400 with ApiVersionUnspecified is returned.

How can I force version for all controllers except the ping controller.